# Redirect everything after a Querystring to another page using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am working on a site that is featuring two multiple page redirects based on query strings. The problem is that these pages are now giving us a 404 error

URL 1 is something like

> website.com?queryhome=productname-546-axdd

URL 2 is something like

> website.com?querynonhome=productname-546-asx

I am trying to get everything in URL 1 to go to homepage and URL 2 to goto website.com/reviews-page

I tried the following for URL 1

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^queryhome=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.website.com  [R=301,L]
```

and the following for URL 2

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^querynohome=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.website.com/reviews-page  [R=301,L]
```

But neither seems to work.

Any sort of help in this matter would be appreciated. As is evident, this is the first time I am trying to tackle a URL which has a query string.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is the problem here:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^queryhome=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.website.com  [R=301,L]
```

Which will match query string `queryhome=1234` due to `[0-9]*` only but NOT `queryhome=productname-546-axdd`

You need to use following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^queryhome=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website.com/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^querynohome=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website.com/reviews-page? [R=301,L]
```

#### Please read: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Thank you anubhava, I am going to try that. And for the second URL - do I use a similar first query and change the rewrite rule to http://website.com/reviews-page/? --- ?

Comment: Worked perfectly mate! Thank you very much! I am going to read the Introduction post you linked.